# Sinon.js stub an anonymous function inside an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, sinon

So I'm unit-testing my code and I face a problem with testing an anonymous function being called inside the function that I'm unit-testing.
The reason for why I didn't make the anonymous function an instance named function, is because I need the closure of some of the variables from the unit-tested function to be used inside the anonymous function.
Example to illustrate:

```
function funcBeingTested(done, arg1) {
    var self = this; 
    ...
    self.array.push({
        "arguments": [
            "x", "y", function (error, result) {
                // do some stuff with arg1...
                done(error, arg1);
            }, "z"
        ]
    });
    ...
    self.run(); // Eventually will call the anonymous function above from 'self.array'
}
```

Now, my question is there a way to test what's going on inside that anonymous function using sinon.js ?
 Someway I could call it with specific arguments as part of the unit test of `funcBeingTested()` ?

**Edit:**
To clear up any misconception about what I'm trying to achieve,
I wish to be able to unit test the **anonymous function** it-self and cover all it's possible branches to get 100% coverage. I already know how to check if the `done()` callback was called, and with what args using sinon.js, the problem is how would I test the anonymous function in an isolation, and call it with specific arguments to cover all possible branches.

Comment: If a function isn't reachable from "the outside", Sinon can't do anything with it. Isn't it possible to pass `done` and `arg1` to a separate method, instead of using an anonymous function?

Answer (score 1):

You can test the anonymous function by defining the `done` function and spying on it. You need to know if this function is called with the right arguments when the anonymous function is called.

For example:

```
// Define the `done` function.
var doneFunction = function (error, args) {
  // do something
};

// Spy on the `done` function to register calls.
var doneSpy = sinon.spy(doneFunction);

// Test the funcBeingTested
funcBeingTested(doneFunction, someArg);

// Check that doneFunction was called
assert(doneSpy.calledWith(someArg));
```

You can read more about the [Spy API for Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/docs/)

Comment: Oh I hadn't realized that that may be all that's being asked :) I thought that the goal was to spy on the anonymous function itself, but reading back the question it may be sufficient to spy on what it _returns_. Although you should pass `doneSpy` to `funcBeingTested`, not `doneFunction`.

Comment: @gnerkus What I meant is that I want to be able to test the anonymous function to get 100% coverage, I know how I could test if the callback was called and with what arguments, the problem is how do I test the anonymous function in an isolation ? How do I call it to begin with, an how do I pass it arbitrary arguments so I could cover all possible branches ?